# How to show company logo in report generated through python code in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a report I want to customize to add the company logo to the report, the problem is the whole report is generated by code. I want to print the company logo on the report, I can print the company name which indicates its working but with the logo, it seems due to path issues it does not seem to work.
Here is my code with a snippet of what I have done so far.

```py
def get_pdf(self, options, minimal_layout=True):
        if not config['test_enable']:
            self = self.with_context(commit_assetsbundle=True)

        base_url = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('report.url') or self.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().get_param('web.base.url')
        rcontext = {
            'mode': 'print',
            'base_url': base_url,
            'company': self.env.company,
        }

        body = self.env['ir.ui.view'].render_template(
            "account_reports.print_template",
            values=dict(rcontext),
        )
        body_html = self.with_context(print_mode=True).get_html(options)
        logging.info(self.env.user.company_id.name)
        logging.info(self.env.user.company_id.logo)
        test = "<header>"\
               "<img style='width: 7.0cm; height: 1.8cm;' src='/web/binary/{}' alt='logo'/>"\
               "</header>".format(self.env.user.company_id.logo)
        ttt = bytes(test, 'utf-8')
```

Like I said it displays the company's name but not the logo even though the logo is set in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to fix it, I remembered that odoo has an image_data_url function that it uses to get the path to an image stored in the database and display in qweb report template, so I checked and found the function in odoo.tools and I called the function in my model passing the company logo as an argument to the function and calling it in the image src attribute, so it looked like this

````py
from odoo import tools
test = "<header style='margin-left: 750px;'>"\
               "<img style='width: 7.0cm; height: 1.8cm;'" \
               "src='{}' alt='logo'/>"\
               "</header>". \
               format(tools.image_data_uri(self.env.user.company_id.logo))
        ttt = bytes(test, 'utf-8')```
````